# How do i view which Gap I should be protecting?

Tags: madden-21

I'm trying to do the Gaps drill in Madden, but I cant figure out which gap I need to protect.  I tried pressing LT + X, but I dont see anything that indicates a gap.  Could someone explain to me how to tell which gap my selected player needs to fill?  A screenshot might be helpful if it's hard to explain.

Comment: I never played this game, but a quick search gave me [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSxtaRC76Ak) about how to fill gaps on defense in madden 20, maybe it could help you. (if yes don't hesitate to self answer your question when you understand how to do it ^^)

Comment: It had some interesting points that will help me out on defense.  I think maybe you are just supposed to look from the coach perspective and see where everyone is going.

Comment: Glad it was of some help to you ^^